# Intellij android unit tests give java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I've got an Android project that I'm trying to write unit tests for. My Android app has a file called 'Command.java' that holds my Command class. In my unit tests I'm trying to create some instances of this Command class for testing purposes. My unit tests compile fine, but after they are deployed to the Android Simulator I get the following error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myapp.Command.

It looks like the unit tests don't know about the Command class during runtime. I've checked that the Unit Tests module has my Android app as a dependency with scope 'Provided'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Provided" means that the dependency will be "provided" to the class by container or whoever is running the class, and it should not package the dependency during the deployment.

In your case the scope should be "Test" or "Compile".

If you run your test outside of the simulator, then the class is available. For running test cases in the simulator, the code is packaged and the above mentioned rule is applied.